# Material UI Linear Progress Bar dependent on state not animating

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm trying to utilize an indeterminate progress bar while fetching the data to display inside of a syntax highlighter component. The progress bar background displays but it doesn't have any animation over it. I've perused a few solutions ([Material-UI LinearProgress bar not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476405/material-ui-linearprogress-bar-not-working), [Material UI linear progress animation when using data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929977/material-ui-linear-progress-animation-when-using-data)) but none of them account for hooks or an indeterministic bar. Any help is much appreciated.

```
export default function ViewLog() {
  let { filename } = useParams();
  const [log, setLogData] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/logs/" + filename)
      .then((response: any) => {
        try {
          setLoading(false);
          setLogData(response.data.content);
        } catch (error) {
          alert("Bad server request... error: " + error);
        }
      });
  }, [filename]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>{filename}</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <LinearProgress />
      ) : (
        <SyntaxHighlighter style={theme} language="json" showLineNumbers={true}>
          {log}
        </SyntaxHighlighter>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Where are you trying to set the value of the progress bar? I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: No value, it’s indeterminate @Christian

Comment: well, but you still need to set the value to *something*, how else do you expect the component to animate/change? Perhaps you weren't looking for a progress bar but a spinner?

Comment: @ChristianFritz The animation is handled automatically by the component. The indeterminate linear progress does not require any props. https://material-ui.com/components/progress/#linear-indeterminate

Comment: ah, thanks, @RyanCogswell! I didn't know.